# build a character chain with successive years

Tags: r, data.table, seq

I have a table with startYear, endYear and I want to create a dimension Year as "startYear,endYear"

```
dt<- data.table(
startYear=c("1994","1995","2013"),
endYear=c("1995","2000","2021"))
```

I want the following dt table

```
dt<- data.table(
startYear=c("1994","1995","2013"),
endYear=c("1995","2000","2021"),
Year = c("1994,1995","1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000","2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020,2021")
```

I try

```
dt$Year<- paste(seq(from = dt$startYear,
                          to = dt$endYear, by = 1))
```

but I get an error message

```
Error in seq.default(from = test$startYear, to = test$endYear, by = 1) : 
  'from' must be of length 1
```

I do not know how to change that to work properly.
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The literal expected output ...

```r
dt[, Year := mapply(function(a, b) paste(seq(a, b), collapse = ","), startYear, endYear) ]
#    startYear endYear                                    Year
#       <char>  <char>                                  <char>
# 1:      1994    1995                               1994,1995
# 2:      1995    2000           1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000
# 3:      2013    2021 2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2...
```

But if you're planning on doing anything with the numbers internally later (not just a collapsed string), it might be useful to deal with `Year` as a list-column, usable in `data.table` and `dplyr` natively, perhaps less aesthetic in base R but it can still work there, too, depending on your use-case.

```r
dt[, Year := Map(seq, startYear, endYear) ]
#    startYear endYear                              Year
#       <char>  <char>                            <list>
# 1:      1994    1995                         1994,1995
# 2:      1995    2000     1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000
# 3:      2013    2021 2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,...
```